# Does loading fewer classes with custom runtime images in java 9 reduce memory RAM consumption?

Tags: java, java-9

With the module linking and custom runtime image creation features of JDK9 can a program have a lower RAM memory footprint in JDK9 than the same program with the standard JRE8 in JDK8? I imagine this would be because there are fewer classes to load from the classpath. It seems as though the RAM savings that would depend on whether the JVM lazily loads class definitions into RAM when an app starts up.

Comment: I'm not sure why the down- and close votes. This is a question that seems like it has a verifiable answer (can Java 9 save RAM by limiting resources it loads).

Comment: Isn’t that the purpose of building a custom runtime image containing fewer classes?